# transform Count consecutive integers

Tags: python, pandas, count, transform

i have a dataset like

```
id
1
2
3
4
7
8
```

i want my output as:

```
id   count
1     4
2     4
3     4
4     4
7     2
8     2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `df['count'] = df.groupby(df['id'].diff().ne(1).cumsum())['id'].transform('size')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `Series` for consecutive integers by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), compare for not equal `1` by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and add cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
s = df['id'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
```

Then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['count'] = s.map(s.value_counts())
```

Or [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['count'] = s.groupby(s).transform('size') 

print (df)
   id  count
0   1      4
1   2      4
2   3      4
3   4      4
4   7      2
5   8      2
```

Comment: It has worked..Thanks a lot both of you :) Actually i was using shift function with group-by